# Concept about rate limiter constructed by redis cluster

Tags: redis, rate-limiting, redis-cluster

I Have a concept problem about rate limiter constructed by redis/cluster mode.
My problem is if I choose token bucket algorithm for rate limiter and use just one redis server, it works well. However if the traffic of redis is too much now, I would like to use redis/cluster mode for horizontal-scaling, but as I know, the redis/cluster mode is eventually consistent, so I think the value of each redis node will not be strongly consistent at the same time, the rate limiter will sometimes have some wrong calculation right? If so, how do I fix the issue, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis Cluster mode is *eventually consistent* from master node to replica nodes. Any change is *immediate* within the master node itself. So if you are reading only from master nodes, consistency would not be an issue.

Comment: [sazzad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4021802/sazzad),  Thank you very much, but as I know redis cluster use gossip protocol to sync data between all nodes, does it can guarantee all master nodes will have the data at the same time? For example, if I update data in master node1, but other server read data from master node2, the data will must be consistent right or not?  Thank you.

Comment: @Ethan Same data does not reside in multiple masters. So there is no _data_ to sync among masters. Masters sync their node status which does not effect data consistency. Please read more how Redis cluster mode distributes data. There are many resources available online. Google them. PS: [This](https://redis.io/docs/reference/cluster-spec/#overview-of-redis-cluster-main-components) is one of them.

Comment: [sazzad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4021802/sazzad), thank you very much.